# Which t-structure extend from subcategories of compact objects uniquely?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories, t-structure

Let $T$ be a compactly generated triangulated category, that is, $T$ is closed with respect to small coproducts and equals its own smallest triangulated subcategory closed with respect to coproducts and contains its subcategory $T_0$ of compact objects, which is essentially small. Let $t_0$ be a $t$-structure on $T_0$. My question is: when $t_0$ extends uniquely to a smashing $t$-structure on $T$, that is, both "halves" of $t$ should be $\coprod$-closed (actually, this assumption is automatic for the "left" of these halves) and $t_0$-truncations of compact objects should coincide with the $t$-ones? I can only prove the existence of an extension of this sort (since one can take the corresponding  compactly generated $t$-structure), whereas uniqueness requires certain  restrictive assumptions.

Comment: Work on analogs of the telescope conjecture in triangulated categories may be relevant, since localizations give examples of $t$-structures, and the telescope conjecture is about the uniqueness of extension of a localization from the compact objects to the whole category. From that perspective, I might guess that restrictive assumptions are unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry; are you sure?:) My impression was that in the telescope conjecture one does not assume that the corresponding shift-stable t-structure restricts to compact objects. Moreover, a stable t-structure is also a weight structure, and I know that the answer to the weight structure version of my question is positive.

Comment: I guess not :). The classical case of the telescope conjecture asks whether $K(n)$-localization is equivalent to $T(n)$-localization, given that they invert the same morphisms between compact objects. But of course, neither the $K(n)$ nor $T(n)$ localization of a compact object is practically ever compact, so I was wrong to say that it came down to lifting a localization from the category of compact objects, exactly as you point out. Sorry!

Comment: Would you consider it "restrictive" to assume that the $t$-structure on compact objects is bounded?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid this condition. However, currently I only now the proof if $t_0$ is bounded and the heart is a length category; thus it would be interesting to generalize. As about the telescope conjecture: it appears that a certain re-formulation (that probably makes the conjecture strongly), exists; yet I don't remember the reference.